# How to transform RedirectMatch to RewriteCond in htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Could you help me please to transform this functions to "rewritecond" format?
I need to change from this format:

`RedirectMatch 301 ^/folder_A/([^/]+/.+?)\.html$ /$1/`

`RedirectMatch 301 ^/folder_A/([^/.]+\.html)$ /$1`

To something like this:

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} XXXXX
RewriteRule XXXXX [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} XXXXX
RewriteRule XXXXX [L,R=301]

Here my actual .htaccess file:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^tienda_2011/([^/]+/.+?)\.html$ /store_copia/es/$1/ [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^tienda_2011/([^/.]+\.html)$ /store_copia/es/$1 [L,R=301]

#RedirectMatch 301 ^/tienda_2011/([^/]+/.+?)\.html$ /store_copia/es/$1/
#RedirectMatch 301 ^/tienda_2011/([^/.]+\.html)$ /store_copia/es/$1

# So "RewriteBase" should be:
# RewriteBase /store/cart 
RewriteBase /tienda_2011
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(png|gif|ico|swf|jpe?g|js|css)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php?sef_rewrite=1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} .*\/catalog\/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html !-f
RewriteRule . index.php?sef_rewrite=1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `RewriteCond`. Just pattern in `RewriteRule` will be be able to handle this:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+/.+?)\.html$ /$1/ [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+?)-es(\.html)$ /$1$2 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+\.html)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Could you help me please with RewriteCond?

Comment: For which URL it didn't work and what is location of this .htaccess? If there more rules then place these rules before other rules?

Comment: At this moment are in Test website. The RedirectMatch works OK except for the fact that it added "?sef_rewrite=1" at the end of the URL. 
I asked in the forum builder ecommerce script and they told me to clear this statement at the end I have to change the redirect "RedirectMatch" with "RewriteCond + RewriteRule". Thats why I need to change

Comment: All that means you have more conflicting rules in your .htaccess. Place your latest .htaccess in your question and tell me answers of all questions I asked in my previous comment so that I can help you.

Comment: .htaccess file added to original post

Comment: You still haven't answered my questions. **For which URL it didn't work and what is location of this .htaccess?**

Comment: Also you need to place these rules just below `RewriteEngine on` line.

Comment: For which URL it didn't work and what is location of this .htaccess?  www.mxtotal.com/tienda_2011/ is the main URL. The htaccess is located under same directory (tienda_2011)

Comment: ok what is `folder_A` in above rule? Is it same as `tienda_2011`? Also pls tell what URL are you entering in your browser that is not getting redirected?

Comment: Yes `folder_A` is `tienda_2011`. Example URL: [link]http://www.mxtotal.com/tienda_2011/motocross/taller-cross.html

Comment: ok check my updated rules, these one need to be **just below `RewriteEngine on` line**

Comment: OK, it works perfectly now. 
Thank you very much for your help. I am very grateful. 

Take this opportunity to talk to you about other related question, see if you can help me again: 

Some of the URL I want to redirect with this function `RewriteRule ^([^/.]+\.html)$ /$1 [L,R=301]` have the following termination: "... product_name-es.html" and I need to be redirected deleting the "-es" and looks like this: "... product_name.html" . The problem is that this ending is not on all URL of products, only a half of them.     Thanks and sorry for abusing your time

Comment: Wow! It works perfect. 
Your support is much better than most customer service out there. 
Thank you. I do not know how to thank this help.

Comment: You're most welcome, glad it all worked out for you.